# EDMX complex types

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework in my mvc application (asp.net). I am using a bunch of stored procedure with no problem, except for one of them. This stored procedure looks like this:

```
select
    @PosteID = HpoPosteID
from
    [Corporatifs_AQ].[dbo].[RhEmplPost]
where
    HemEmployeID = @HemEmployeID

exec [dbo].[usp_RhServiceSuperieurPoste] @PosteID, @CompOrgaServ OUTPUT

select
    distinct
    emp.HemPrenom,
    emp.HemNom,
    emp.HemInitiale,
    aff.HafDescription,
    emp.HemEmployeID,
    pos.HcoCompOrgaID
from
    dbo.ObtenirCompOrgaEnfants( NULL,@CompOrgaServ,1,NULL ) enf 
    join [dbo].[RhCompPost] pos on pos.HcoCompOrgaID = enf.HcoCompOrgaID
    join [dbo].[RhAffectation] aff on aff.HpoPosteID = pos.HpoPosteID
    join [dbo].[RhPoste] poste on aff.HpoPosteID =  poste.HpoPosteID
    join [dbo].[RhEmploye] emp on emp.HemEmployeID = aff.HemEmployeID
where
    ((HemNom LIKE @HemLettres) OR
     (HemPrenom LIKE @HemLettres))
```

Entity framework is treating this procedure like it's returning an int (`HpoPosteID`), but it's also returning (select distinct) more values, so I would need a complex type. It was working before, but I deleted the edmx to create a new one, I don't know what happened..

In the edmx I deleted, the function to call the procedure looked like this:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<usp_RhEmployeNomPrenomSelect_Result> usp_RhEmployeNomPrenomSelectService(string hemLettres, Nullable<int> hemDate, Nullable<int> hemEmployeID)
    {...
```

Note that the complexe type returned was RhEmployeNomPrenomSelect, which was the complexe type for another stored procedure(RhEmployeNomPrenomSelect) but RhEmployeNomPrenomSelectService returns the same fields so entity framework reused the object

But now, it's returning an int, for the same procedure:

```
 public virtual int usp_RhEmployeNomPrenomSelectService(string hemLettres, Nullable<int> hemDate, Nullable<int> hemEmployeID)
    {
```

Comment: If you invoke the Stored Procedure from within SSMS, what output do you get in both the Results pane and the Messages pane? Do you get multiple result-sets or just a single one? Entity Framework handles multiple-results output differently, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I see that your sproc calls another sproc `RhServiceSuperieurPoste` - does that sproc return any data to the output at all? If so, maybe EF is picking that one up.

Comment: The stored procedure is returning a couple of data, I was using the same stored procedure in the edmx I was using before... It was returning a complexe type..See the edited question

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of the procedure.